# Using named range as RowSource in ComboBox failing when named range in row

Tags: excel, combobox, named-ranges, vba

I have ComboBoxes, used in UserForms, that use named ranges as RowSource.

All my named ranges were produced from `Create names from selections` in Excel of Selection.CreateNames in VBA.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim row As Integer 'In the example, row = 1, but in real life I'll want to create many named ranges from items listed as rows.
Dim lastCol As Integer 'Needed because my named ranges will vary in length
Dim ws As Worksheet 'Where my data is

Set ws = Worksheets("tests")

row = 1
lastCol = ws.Cells(row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

ws.Range(Cells(row, 1), Cells(row, lastCol)).Select

'Create the named range
Selection.CreateNames Left:=True

'Assign the named range (via its name, found in column 1) to the ComboBox RowSource
ComboBoxSampleForSO.RowSource = ws.Cells(row, 1).Value

End Sub
```

Here are the items in my Sheet "tests"
[image]

The `Name manager` tells me all my names are correct (i.e. they all list the correct elements):

[image]

The problem: only the first element is displayed in the ComboBox.

This problem does not occur when:

- the named ranges are created from data in a column rather than in a row
- I create dropdown lists in my worksheets directly (using `Data validation`).

Can I fix this?

Comment: Show your example row and the code used for using VBA to call Selection.CreateNames (and the VBA for loading the ComboBox with range)

Comment: Is the ComboBox on a userform?

Comment: Take a look at the `Combobox.List` property.

Comment: Dumb answer... but do you really need to source to be a row rather than a column?

Comment: @dbmitch Code and images were added. The ComboBox is indeed on a userform.

Comment: @Doug I did, but didn't find anything that helped. What should I be looking for?

Comment: @Absinthe I'd rather not, but will revert to that If I have to.

Comment: You can assign a range to the.List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you've run into an Excel feature.

The only way to do this is with VBA - either with a Worksheet Activate function or a button - that updates the Rowsource with list additem

Even then that won't work unless combobox is on a userform.

```
' Substitute your range name here
Const HORIZ_RANGE   As String = "Row1Range"

Dim varListVals As Variant
Dim intItem As Integer

' Returns two dimension array from your range of cells
varListVals = Application.Range(HORIZ_RANGE).Cells

ComboBox1.Clear

For intItem = LBound(varListVals, 2) To UBound(varListVals, 2)
    ComboBox1.AddItem varListVals(1, intItem)
Next intItem
```

Comment: Good hint. Looping through my columns and using    Me.ComboBoxSampleForSO.AddItem ws.Cells(row, col).Value will work. Better, looping through my named range items (For Each item in Names(ws.Cells(row, 1).Value).RefersToRange) gives me the expected behavior. I'd very gladly accept your answer if written out, but am willing to write out the full answer myself if you'd rather.

Comment: If you're using a userform now with ComboBox1 - code will work. Takes first dimension of array and uses AddItem to load combobox